SenderEmailAddress/To/SenderName fields blank via Outlook COM
Per the title, these fields are blank. That same message in Outlook certainly isn't missing these headers.
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" -ErrorAction Stop
$OutlookApp = New-Object -ComObject "Outlook.Application"

$OutlookNS = $OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$OutlookNS.Logon()

$RootFolder = $OutlookNS.Folders() | Where-Object { $_.FullFolderPath -eq "\\foo@bar.com" }
$TargetFolder = $RootFolder.Folders() | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Inbox" }

$StartDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$EndDate = (Get-Date)

$filter = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"">='$($StartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss"))' And ""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived""<='$($EndDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss"))'"
$MailItems = $TargetFolder.Items.Restrict($filter) | Where-Object { $_ -is [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem] }

$MailItems.Item(1) | Select-Object SenderEmailAddress, "To", Subject, SenderName, ReceivedTime, LastModificationTime

Here's the properties from one of the messages. The properties exist; however, some have null data (or their COMObject is null).



Has Data
No Data




Actions
AutoForwarded


AlternateRecipientAllowed
AutoResolvedWinner


Application
BCC


BodyFormat
BillingInformation


Class
Body


ConversationID
Categories


ConversationIndex
CC


ConversationTopic
Companies


CreationTime
DeleteAfterSubmit


DeferredDeliveryTime
FlagIcon


DownloadState
FlagRequest


EnableSharedAttachments
FlagStatus


EntryID
HasCoverSheet


ExpiryTime
HTMLBody


FlagDueBy
IsConflict


FormDescription
IsIPFax


GetInspector
IsMarkedAsTask


Importance
Links


InternetCodepage
MarkForDownload


ItemProperties
Mileage


LastModificationTime
NoAging


MAPIOBJECT
OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested


MessageClass
OutlookInternalVersion


Parent
OutlookVersion


ReceivedByEntryID
Permission


ReceivedOnBehalfOfEntryID
PermissionService


ReceivedTime
PermissionTemplateGuid


ReminderTime
PropertyAccessor


RetentionExpirationDate
ReadReceiptRequested


Saved
ReceivedByName


SaveSentMessageFolder
ReceivedOnBehalfOfName


SenderEmailType
RecipientReassignmentProhibited


SendUsingAccount
Recipients


Sent
ReminderOverrideDefault


SentOn
ReminderPlaySound


Session
ReminderSet


Size
ReminderSoundFile


Subject
RemoteStatus


TaskCompletedDate
ReplyRecipientNames


TaskDueDate
ReplyRecipients


TaskStartDate
RetentionPolicyName


TaskSubject
RTFBody


ToDoTaskOrdinal
Sender


UnRead
SenderEmailAddress



SenderName



Sensitivity



SentOnBehalfOfName



Submitted



To



VotingOptions



VotingResponse




MailItem object in OOM does not expose a property called From. Use SenderName / SenderEmailAddress /etc.. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem for more details.
You might also want to use Namespace.GetDefaultFolder / Store.GetDefaultFolder to retrieve the Inbox folder (olFolderInbox) rather than retrieve it by name.

I'm not sure where I got From, staring at this for too long, I guess. But SenderName, SenderEmailAddress, and To are still blank. Nothing in the returned object shows any e-mail address.

Do you get the value for Subject?

Yep, including a value for ReceivedTime and LastModificationTime. This is from the same code I used to export certain attachments given a time range, which worked great. At the time, I didn't care about the sender or the recipients.

Are you sure you don't end up with a ReportItem object, whcih does not expose these properties? Do you see missing data for all returned items?

During the Restrict call, I ensure the object is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem, so I would figure it's not ReportItem. As for what's missing data, I've added a table to the OP.

Hmmm... Does $MailItems.Item(1).Display() show the expected data?

$MailItems.Item(1).Display() works normally.

OK, so the message is good. What does $MailItems.Item(1).Body give you?

Nothing, it is null.
